# Hunspell not working in Lyx

Tags: lyx, dictionaries

I am using Lyx 2.2.4 supported by Linux Mint 19.2. I have Hunspell dictionaries loaded in usr/share/hunspell but they are not recognised by Lyx. Preference/paths/Hunspell is greyed out and I cannot load the path. I have checked out the info in wiki.lyx.org/Devel/Hunspell#toc3 and as far as I can see everything is OK. I've uninstalled, reinstalled, reconfigured etc but to no avail. Help with this would be much appreciated

Comment: What does you setting for 'alternate language' say? Here I had a similar problem because of a messed up setting there. With `\alternate_language "en"` in my `~/.lyx/preferences` it works with spellchecker at GUI set to enchant, and hunspell dicts installed.

Comment: I am having the same problem and this didn't work for me, the box for Hunspell's path is still greyed out!?

Answer (score 1):

It's a configuration issue. If LyX has not been compiled with `--use-hunspell`, then Hunspell support is disabled. You can either compile yourself or ask your packager to provide a version with hunspell support.

Comment: oh too bad to hear it is so complicated, but thanks for the answer!! :-)