# Lyx: share/sync personnal dictionary among computers?

Tags: lyx, ubuntu, spelling

I am using Lyx and would like that the words saved with `Add to personal dictionary` can be re-used on two different (Ubuntu) computers.

One solution I can think of would be to have my personal dictionary saved on a syncing folder (Dropbox, etc), and linking the local location of dictionaries to it? I am, however, not able to see where Lyx saves the personal dictionary?

I've read it should be in `~/.lyx` on Ubuntu, but ther and don't see such file:

```
$ sudo find /.  -name "pwl_*dict"
```

results in nothing...

Thanks!

Comment: Try searching for `pwl_*.dict` elesewhere

Comment: good point @JSpitzm ! I searched everywhere on the disk (see update), and cannot find it... strange! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is dependent on the spellchecker you use (Tools > Preferences > Language Settings > Spellchecker).

For "Hunspell" and "Aspell", LyX saves the personal dictionaries in `<user dir>/pwl_<lang>.dict`, where `<user dir>` is the user directory (normally `~/.lyx` on linux) and `<lang>` the lyx language name.

For "Enchant", the file is saved in the enchant user configuration directory, by default (on linux)  `~/.config/enchant/<langid>.dic`, where `<langid>` is a BCP47 identifier such as `en_US`.

Comment: thanks! unfortunately, it is not there, see updated post.

Comment: I suppose you use the enchant spellchecker. Please see the update of my comment.

Comment: awesome! I was indeed using Enchant! Found it! Interestingly, I notice that I have `en.dic`, `en_GB.dic` and `en_US.dic`. Do you happen to know which parameters in the lyx or document options dictate which one is used?

Comment: Yes: `en_GB.dic` is used for "English (UK)", `en_US.dic` for "English (USA)" and plain "English". `en.dic` is probably from a different app that uses enchant.

Comment: ok, I figured it out: it is the `Document -> Settings -> Language` that dictates this. Choosing just `English` will write to `en.dic`, while choosing "English (UK)" will write into `en_GB.dic` as you noted! I will now check if I can share/sync that file among multiple computers. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: And because you mention Hunspell and seem very knowledgeable about Lyx: is there any chance you could look at this post about installing Hunspell in Lyx? I am facing the same issue (path greyed out) but unfortunately the post has remained unsolved so far... https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520610/hunspell-not-working-in-lyx#comment1648222_520610 Thanks!!

Comment: Done, see my answer there.